# how to make grid column as drop down list for all rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
colNames: ['A','B','C','D'],
                colModel: [
                      { name: 'A', index: 'A', width: 90 },
                      { name: 'B', index: 'B', width: 100 },
                      { name: 'C', index: 'C', width: 70 },
                      { name: 'D', index: 'D', edittype: 'select', width: 100, editoptions: { value: { 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No'}} }

                    ],
```

My concerns here is, I am displaying A B C D values from db2... for Last Column do I need to put default drop down list for all the rows.

Comment: Please format this code and question properly. To format code, select the code, and click the button that has binary numbers 101 or use the shortcut - `Ctrl+K` or `Command+K`.

Comment: Here I updated thanks for letting me know.. problem is.. 
Column D.. I need to display as dropdown list for selected values Yes and No... for all the rows in the grid..

Suppose if I am getting three Columns from database..A B C values I am displaying from database but D column should be default for all the rows... 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `editable` property in D's definition:

```
{
    name: 'D',
    index: 'D',
    edittype: 'select',
    width: 100,
    editable: true,
    editoptions: { value: { 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No' } }
}
```

Without the `editable` property, it won't work as far as I know, but i could be wrong. For a working example and code, you can see these resources:

1. A simplified version on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzqxz/)
2. jqGrid demos - [Row Editing > Input Types](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: Yes I included that too? but its not working for me.. 
here is the column I decalred.. 

 { name: 'Resolution Code',editype:true, index: 'Resolution Code', edittype: 'select', width: 100, editoptions: { value: { 1: 'Resolved by Specialist', 2: 'No Error-Market Conditions'}} },
                ],

Comment: the `edittype` property is repeated in the code you've pasted above, and there is no `editable`. if it's not working, can you provide a link where the problem is reproducible? use http://jsfiddle.com if you want to setup a quick demo.